# Max in an object list

Tags: python, search, max

I have a list of object with the following structure:

```
class video:
def __init__(self,level,videoID,title, url, views, comments, likes, dislikes):
    self.level= level
    self.id = videoID
    self.title = str(title).encode('utf-8')
    self.url = url
    self.views = views
    self.comments = comments
    self.likes = likes
    self.dislikes = dislikes
```

I'm trying to get the video with the maximum likes on a specific level.

All the videos are in **videosData**

I've tried

```
def maxLikes (depth): 
    concernData = []

    for x in xrange(0,len(videosData)):
        if (videosData[x].level == depth):
            concernData.append(videosData[x])

    return max(concernData, key = lambda x: x.likes)
```

I return a value but not the maximum and I really don't understand where I went wrong.

All the code is avaible here : https://github.com/kwnovi/melihat/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Your `maxLikes()` can be simplified to `return max((v for v in videosData if v.level == depth), key=lambda v: v.likes)`.

Comment: How do you know you are not returning the maximum here? You get back the `video` instance with the highest `likes` value for the given `depth`, your code looks correct.

Comment: I know this is not the maximum because I print all the elements of videosData, and there are higher values for a specific level. Thanks Martijn, I've simplified the code but it does not change the result.

Comment: so when you do `[v.likes for v in videosData if v.level == depth]` you get a list of likes for a given level, can you share that list?

Comment: Yeah sure, `[u'2558', u'8690', u'1926', u'384', u'8690', u'5085', u'5085', u'3950', u'206006']`, and the max method return **8690**

Comment: Those are strings, not integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing *strings*. These are ordered lexicographically, so first by comparing the first character, then the second, etc. This sorts `'80'` after `'9'`, for example.

You need to convert those to integers if you want to compare them *numerically*:

```
return max((v for v in videosData if v.level == depth),
           key=lambda v: int(v.likes))
```

where I simplified the filtering on level into a generator expression.